# Difference between FMS and OBD

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus, obd

What is the difference between FMS and OBD. Whether OBD is a standard or protocol.

Recently I am working on a GPS device to tap the CAN bus in order to integrate with our fleet management system. In configuration I found two options: FMS and OBD, and couldn't find the difference between them. On Googling I came across J1939. Both FMS and OBD are compliant with J1939. What is J1939, as there is a separate connector available?

If both options are available, which one should I go for? On Googling I found FMS is used by many vehicles and that OBD is used only in the USA.

Can someone provide me with details on these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If FMS is available I'd stick with that as it seems to be exactly what you want. From the wiki, "SAE J1939 defines five layers in the seven-layer OSI network model, and this includes the Controller Area Network (CAN) ISO 11898 specification (using only the 29-bit/"extended" identifier) for the physical and data-link layers. Under J1939/11 and J1939/15, the data rate is specified as 250 kbit/s, with J1939/14 specifying 500 kbit/s. The session and presentation layers are not part of the specification"

Comment: as to the differences OBD is more a diagnostic tool while FMS allows for vehicle telemetry data.